# Reference resolution in python

Tags: python, nlp, coreference-resolution

Im trying to perform reference resolution on a short story (a few sentences).

I understand some of the theory behind reference resolution, I'm lost on how to start. I'm not asking for the answer I just need some sort of tip.

- [Input example (multiple sentences)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRc2W.png)
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHG1C.png)
- [Formal method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw4GS.png)

We can't use any prebuilt modules besides the `TRIPS` ontology and `numpy`

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the 3 images you have as text? Just so we can help you without typing the images out

Comment: Sorry my bad. Here you go: first one: “Sam gave him a drink”
     (NAME “Sam” ONT::MALE-PERSON S2)
     (VERB “gave” ONT::GIVING V2)
     (PRO “him” ONT::MALE-PERSON H1)
     (A “drink” ONT::BEVERAGES D1), second one: (COREF S2 S1)
(COREF H1 J1)
(COREF I1 D1)
— i.e., the two instances of Sam are the same person
— i.e., the pronoun in the second sentence refers to Jack — i.e., the pronoun in the third sentence refers to the drink, third: The format of a basic entry is
(<spec> <word> <type> <DE>)

Comment: The input in general would be around 3 sentences with their description given in parentheses right after the sentence